# ParseNetworkString will not parse 21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080

Tags: winapi, ipv6, winsock

I'm trying to find a way to parse a user entered IP address information, e.g.:

- `192.168.100.10`
- `192.168.100.10:80`
- `21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2`
- `21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A`
- `[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080`
- `21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080`
- `www.microsoft.com`
- `www.microsoft.com:80`

The WinAPI function [ParseNetworkString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-parsenetworkstring) claims to be able to parse all these formats (the list came from the documentation). And a lot of them do indeed parse. But some fail:

- `192.168.100.10` ✅
- `192.168.100.10:80` ✅
- `21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2` ✅
- `21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A` ✅
- `[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080` ❌
- `21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080` ❌
- `www.microsoft.com` ✅
- `www.microsoft.com:80` ✅

So the pseudocode:

```
NET_ADDRESS_INFO^ addressInfo;
UInt16^           portNumber;
UInt8^            prefixLength;

DWORD res = ParseNetworkString(
      "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080", //NetworkString
      NET_STRING_IPV6_SERVICE_NO_SCOPE, //Types
      addressInfo, portNumber, lengthPrefix);
```

comes back [87 The Parameter is incorrect.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

What am i doing wrong?

## Bonus

In the same way the API says it can parse:

```
192.168.100.10:8080
\____________/ \__/
    |           |
 Address       Port
```

It also claims it can parse:

```
21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080
\_____________________________________/ \__/
                   |                     |
                Address                 Port
```

Some people might object, and claim that the only way to have a **port number** included in a canonical IPv6 address is if the address portion is enclosed in [square backets]. Those people are simply wrong. [<sup>Source: RFC5952</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-6)

In the end, what we want is to be able to pass what the user entered to [**WSAConnectByName**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnectbynamea), which takes:

- `nodeName`: e.g. "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A"
- `serviceName` e.g. "3119"

### Complete Minimal Reproducible Example

```
# Service - where Port is mandatory
# ---------------------------------
# NET_STRING_ANY_SERVICE (where port is mandatory)
#   NET_STRING_ANY_SERVICE_NO_SCOPE
#      NET_STRING_NAMED_SERVICE              (e.g. "www.microsoft.com:80")
#      NET_STRING_IP_SERVICE 
#         NET_STRING_IP_SERVICE_NO_SCOPE   
#            NET_STRING_IPV4_SERVICE          (e.g. "192.168.100.10:80")
#            NET_STRING_IPV6_SERVICE_NO_SCOPE (e.g. "[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A]:8080")    scope is forbidden
#         NET_STRING_IPV6_SERVICE             (e.g. "[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080")  scope is optional
#
# Address - where port is forbidden
# ----------------------------------
# NET_STRING_ANY_ADDRESS
#    NET_STRING_ANY_ADDRESS_NO_SCOPE
#       NET_STRING_NAMED_ADDRESS              (e.g. "www.microsoft.com")
#       NET_STRING_IP_ADDRESS
#          NET_STRING_IP_ADDRESS_NO_SCOPE
#          NET_STRING_IPV4_ADDRESS             (e.g. "192.168.100.10")
#             NET_STRING_IPV6_ADDRESS_NO_SCOPE (e.g. "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A")   scope is forbidden
#          NET_STRING_IPV6_ADDRESS             (e.g. "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2") scope is optinal
#
# Network - where CIDR is required (Scope and port forbidden)
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# NET_STRING_IP_NETWORK
#    NET_STRING_IPV4_NETWORK    (e.g. "192.168.100/24")
#    NET_STRING_IPV6_NETWORK    (e.g. "21DA:D3::/48")


import ctypes
from ctypes import POINTER, Structure, c_ulong, c_ushort, c_ubyte, c_wchar_p, windll, c_uint
from ipaddress import IPv6Address, IPv4Address

# Structures and constants for the WinAPI call

class NET_ADDRESS_INFO(Structure):
    class _U(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("Ipv4Address", ctypes.c_ubyte * 4), 
                    ("Ipv6Address", ctypes.c_ubyte * 16),
                    ("DnsName", ctypes.c_wchar_p)]
    _fields_ = [("Format", c_uint), ("U", _U)]

NET_ADDRESS_FORMAT_UNSPECIFIED = 0
NET_ADDRESS_DNS_NAME = 1
NET_ADDRESS_IPV4 = 2
NET_ADDRESS_IPV6 = 3

NET_STRING_ANY_SERVICE = 0x00000222
NET_STRING_ANY_ADDRESS = 0x00000209

# Load the DLL containing the ParseNetworkString function
iphlpapi = windll.Iphlpapi

# Define the function prototype
iphlpapi.ParseNetworkString.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, c_ulong, POINTER(NET_ADDRESS_INFO), POINTER(c_ushort), POINTER(c_ubyte)]
iphlpapi.ParseNetworkString.restype = c_ulong

# Function to call ParseNetworkString
def call_parse_network_string(network_string):
    address_info = NET_ADDRESS_INFO()
    port_number = c_ushort()
    prefix_length = c_ubyte()

    # First try parsing as a service
    result = iphlpapi.ParseNetworkString(
        network_string,
        NET_STRING_ANY_SERVICE,
        ctypes.byref(address_info),
        ctypes.byref(port_number),
        ctypes.byref(prefix_length)
    )

    # If failed, try parsing as an address
    if result != 0:
        result = iphlpapi.ParseNetworkString(
            network_string,
            NET_STRING_ANY_ADDRESS,
            ctypes.byref(address_info),
            ctypes.byref(port_number),
            ctypes.byref(prefix_length)
        )

        if result != 0:
            return f"Error: {ctypes.WinError(result).strerror}"

    # Determine the format of the address
    if address_info.Format == NET_ADDRESS_IPV4:
        ip = IPv4Address(bytes(address_info.U.Ipv4Address))
    elif address_info.Format == NET_ADDRESS_IPV6:
        ip = IPv6Address(bytes(address_info.U.Ipv6Address))
    elif address_info.Format == NET_ADDRESS_DNS_NAME:
        ip = address_info.U.DnsName
    else:
        ip = "Unspecified"

    return f"Format: {address_info.Format}, Address: {ip}, Port: {port_number.value}"

# Test the function with multiple network strings
network_strings = [
    "192.168.100.10",
    "192.168.100.10:80",
    "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2",
    "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A",
    "[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080",
    "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080",
    "www.microsoft.com",
    "www.microsoft.com:80"
]

for ns in network_strings:
    result = call_parse_network_string(ns)
    print(f'"{ns}" --> {result}')
```

| NetworkString | Format | Address | Port |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "192.168.100.10" | `NET_ADDRESS_IPV4` | 192.168.100.10 | 0 |
| "192.168.100.10:80" | `NET_ADDRESS_IPV4` | 192.168.100.10 | 80 |
| "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2" | `NET_ADDRESS_IPV6` | 21da:d3:0:2f3b:2aa:ff:fe28:9c5a | 0 |
| "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A" | `NET_ADDRESS_IPV6` | 21da:d3:0:2f3b:2aa:ff:fe28:9c5a | 0 |
| "[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080" | `NET_ADDRESS_IPV6` | 21da:d3:0:2f3b:2aa:ff:fe28:9c5a | 8080 |
| "21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080" |  | The parameter is incorrect. |  |
| "www.microsoft.com" |  | The parameter is incorrect. |  |

Comment: 121DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080` is not a valid IPv6 address because it has nine 16-bit words instead of eight.

Comment: @RonMaupin The final `:8080` is not part of the address; it's the port. It's obviously confusing because the address portion is not wrapped in `[]`. But it's obviously not part of the address because there already are 8 words.

Comment: Read [RFC 5952, Section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-6). It explains the problem, and refers and links to RFC 3986. "_This style is NOT RECOMMENDED because of its ambiguity._"

Comment: All that's left is to figure out how to make [**ParseNetworkString**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-parsenetworkstring) behave as documented.

Comment: If you ant the API to work as advertised, then you need to make a bug report to get it fixed. Personally, I wrote all my own IP routines for things like this. I have an IPv4 object, and an IPv6 object, and it will take all proper IPv6 text formats, but it only returns in the RFC 5952 format.

Comment: I'm assuming it's not a bug in Windows. I'm assuming its in my code. Huberus to jump straight to *"it's buggy Windows"*.

Comment: "*So the pseudocode*" - please don't post pseudocode, post a [mcve] of actual code you are having trouble with. As shown, your pseudocode suggests you are passing uninitialized pointers to `ParseNetworkString()`.

Comment: If you assume a bug in your code, it would seem logical to post your code.

Comment: Actually, `[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080` + NET_STRING_IPV6_SERVICE works for me (my Windows x64 has all the latest updates) which is consistent with Luke's answer

Comment: @RonMaupin The amigbuity referred to is when there's a double-colon used to shorten the address. Explicitly listing all 8 fields followed by a port number shouldn't be ambiguous at all.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, but if you allow it like that, you must consider the case where consecutive zero words are replaced by a double colon. It is an all around bad idea, and it has been pretty much dead since IPv6 first came out. People keep trying to revive it.

Comment: @RonMaupin It's perfectly fine for the API to reject an ambiguous service string. But there is nothing ambiguous about `21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A:8080`, it has exactly one interpretation, is a valid interpretation. And if that were not enough to convince the grumpy: it is also documented in the RFC. And even if people still want to argue it - there is no argument over `[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is simply incorrect.  If you disassemble `ParseNetworkString()` you will find it calls `RtlIpv6StringToAddressEx()` which is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv6stringtoaddressexw) as (**emphasis** added):

> The string pointed to by the AddressString parameter must be represented in the form for an IPv6 address string followed by an optional percent character and scope ID string. The IPv6 address and scope ID string **must be enclosed in square brackets**. The right square bracket after the IPv6 address and scope ID string may be followed by an optional colon and a string representation of a port number.

Comment: In other words, it should parse `[21DA:00D3:0000:2F3B:02AA:00FF:FE28:9C5A%2]:8080` just fine. But it doesn't.